# What is this data structure in YAML?

Tags: yaml

I am trying to make the cleanest YAML data structure possible (by clean I mean the least amount of extraneous markup).

What I am trying to create is a list of `sections`, where each `section` is itself a list of different types of objects.

In JSON this would look like

```
{
"sections": [
  [
     {"p": "Words"}
  ],
  [
    {
     "ul": "more words",
     "p": "other"
    } 
  ]
 ]
}
```

This is what I have in YAML so far:

```
sections:
  -
    - p: 'Test words.'

    - ul:
      - "Words"
      - "More words"

  -
    - p: "Other words"
```

I am confused by the dashes.

**In the example above, do both `p` and the `ul` need dashes (to be part of the name object) or is just the first dash necessary?**

i.e. is this functionally the same?

```
sections:
  -
    - p: 'Test words.'
     ul:
      - "Words"
      - "More words"
```

Further, what do dashes with no content after them (like the first dash under sections) denote?

```
sections:
  - // this dash
    - p: 'Test words.'
```

Comment: You're questioning why the YAML syntax is how it is? That's probably the wrong place to ask. This is a place for asking programming questions. The YAML syntax was defined like that, and parsers were written for it. Maybe it would be good to get familiar with the basic syntax and terminology first. There is [my short tutorial](https://www.yaml.info/learn/index.html) and [Learn YAML in Y Minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/). For example, I don't know what you mean by "identifier".

Comment: @tinita thank  you, I adjusted the question with your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON example:

```
{
"sections": [
  [
     {"p": "Words"}
  ],
  [
    {
     "ul": "more words",
     "p": "other"
    } 
  ]
 ]
}
```

can be written like this in YAML:

```
---
sections:
- - p: Words
- - p: other
    ul: more words
```

There are two hyphens (dashes), because it is a nested sequence (aka list, array).

Every sequence item starts with a hyphen in YAML.

The JSON example is also valid YAML because JSON is a subset of YAML.
YAML was invented as an alternative to XML, around the same time as JSON was invented independently.
When the YAML inventors became aware of JSON, they modified their syntax to be compatible with it in version 1.2, but it already supported a compact style similar to JSON.

The example could also be written like this:

```
---
sections:
- [
   {p: Words}
  ]
- [
    {
      ul: more words,
      p: other,
    } 
  ]
```

[More about nested sequences and mappings](https://www.yaml.info/learn/index.html)